# Fazer um form oculto

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um CRUD básico, e eu preciso que quando o usuário clique em EDITAR, abra um form embaixo, ou do lado, não importa, com os campos para ele editar tais informações, e quando clicar em 'OK', o campo desapareça e mostre os campos editados.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM postagens";
        $result = $postagens->select();
        while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<h2><li>' .$array['titulo'].'<h2></li>
            <h4><li>' .$array ['conteudo'].'</li></h4>
            <h4><li>'.$array['id'].'</li></h4>
            <a href="Postagens/editarPost.php"><input type="button" value="Editar"></a>
            <a href="index.php?exid='.$array['id'].'"><input type="button" value="Excluir"></p>';
    ?>
```

Comment: Coloque o código para ficar mais fácil de lhe ajudar

Comment: está usando jquery?

Comment: Não estou usando, mas creio que precise, não entendo muito bem. A ideia seria fazer um form oculto, para quando o usuário clicar em editar, ele aparecer, com a opção de atualizar os campos e dar o submit no mesmo.

Comment: coloquei a respota com jquery aí

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda e disposição. Valeu !

Comment: deu certo? se não deu certo, é só falar!

Comment: coloquei tbm uma opção sem usar jquery, se preferir!

Comment: Jean, defina um id ou pelo menos um name pra cada elemento html seu, assim facilita o controle e manutenção dos elementos da sua pagina

Comment: Consegui, juntei a sua resposta com a do parceiro ali embaixo, e consegui :D eu comecei a ver js, jquery, e afins faz uma semana, então não estou muito familiarizado, mas voces me ajudaram demais, muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Obrigado! Já que resolveu seu problema, escolhe uma das respostas como correta, pra indicar que sua duvida foi resolvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/evLju763/) um exmplo de como fazer show/hide ao form:

```js
// carregar no botão para editar e o form aparece
var btn_editar = document.getElementById('btn_editar');
btn_editar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('form_editar').style.display = 'block';
});


// carregar no botão para esconder o form
var btn_hide = document.getElementById('btn_hide');
btn_hide.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('form_editar').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#form_editar {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_editar">
Editar
</button>
<button id="btn_hide">
Esconder Form
</button>
<form id="form_editar">
<input type="text" placeholder="nome">
<input type="email" placeholder="email">
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/evLju763/)

Answer (score 1):

Coloque esse código com jquery dentro da função ready do javascript para rodá-lo.

**Com jquery:**

```
$('#id-do-botão-editar').click(function(e){
     $('#id-do-form').hide();
     $('#area-com-os-campos-pra-editar').show();
});
```

Chame essa função no evento onclick do seu botão editar:

**Com javascript puro:**

```
function oculta(){
     document.getElementById("id-do-form").style.display= "none";
     document.getElementById("area-com-os-campos-pra-editar").style.display= "inline";
}
```